# Query from contact table Insert to outbox table

Tags: php, mysql

Help me please.
I Want insert from contact table to outbox tabel.

contact:

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` 
 (`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `group_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES (1, 'jala', '+60111', 'friends');
INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES (2, 'jali', '+60222', 'friends');
INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES (3, 'jalu', '+60333', 'friends');
INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES (4, 'kada', '+60444', 'members');
INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES (5, 'kadi','+60555','members');
INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES (6, 'kadu', '+60666', 'members');
```

outbox:

```
CREATE TABLE `outbox`
(`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `text` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;}
```

I Want insert  to outbox tabel.

insert.php

```
$sql =mysql_query("SELECT phone 
                   FROM contacts 
                   WHERE group_name = 'member'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{  $id= $data['id']; $phone= $data['phone'];(phone_number, text) VALUES('$phone','I LOVE YOU') }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO outbox (id,phone_number,text)
SELECT id,phone,'I LOVE YOU'
FROM contacts
WHERE group_name = 'member'
```

Comment: @John Totet Woo: Thank you. Good luck for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `INSERT...SELECT` statement in your query. And also use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**  extention for this.

Example:

```
<?php

    $sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO outbox (id, phone_number, text)
                     SELECT id, phone, ?
                     FROM   contacts
                     WHERE  group_name = ?";

    $text = "I LOVE YOU";
    $group_name = "member";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sqlStatement);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $text);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $group_name);

    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

***Remember to always sanitize your inputs.***